# How to allocate random prefab to one of 3 random public vector2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying for a long time to figure out how to assign a correct prefab (currently a button) to one of the 3 possible positions, with another 2 positions to be one of the incorrect prefabs (also buttons) chosen from an array of the incorrect prefabs.

As the prototype is UI based, I am working with Canvas only.

Will appreciate any help as I cannot quite visualise how this ought to work despite several attempts.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Testing : MonoBehaviour {


    //3 locations where the options are to appear
    Vector2[] positions;
    public Vector2 leftPosition;
    public Vector2 middlePosition;
    public Vector2 rightPosition;

    //list the possible options (iconPrefab) to choose from in an array
    public List<Transform> optionPrefab = new List<Transform> ();
    int optionPrefab_num;

    //state which option is correct for this scene
    public Transform correctOption;



void start()
{
    correctOption = Random.Range (0, 2);

    positions = new Vector2[3];
    leftPosition = positions [Random.Range (0, positions.Length)];


    middlePosition = positions [Random.Range (0, positions.Length)];
    rightPosition = positions [Random.Range (0, positions.Length)];

    Instantiate (correctOption [0], //....to one of the 3 positions listed above);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Instantiate(new[]{leftPosition,middlePosition,rightPosition}[Random.Range(0,3)])` ?

Comment: You initialized `vector2` with `positions = new Vector2[3];` but you never assigned value to each position before using it `leftPosition = positions [Random.Range (0, positions.Length)];` Where do you expect to get that those 3 values to assign to the positions[0],positions[1] and positions[2]?.

Comment: they are public vector2 as listed at the top, and unity required me to add number, so I thought 3 to represent 3 positions i wanted it to consider. guess wrong approach then?

Comment: Thanks user2136963, doesnt seem to be right though considering 15 errors I got :)

Comment: hi Simcha. it's Random.Range (0, 3); (not 2). Read the documentation. Programming is really hard.

Comment: @Simcha You never assigned anything to `positions`. And no, `positions`  is private not public. You have to say where to get that value from. Also `correctOption = Random.Range (0, 2);`? You are assigning int to `Transform` Where do you expect to get those Transform you want to assign to `correctOption`?

Answer (score 1):

If a problem is too hard, you can solve it in steps. I assume, you need fields with positions and transforms public

Instantiate something at a given position:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject ThingToSpawn;
    void Start () 
    {
        if (ThingToSpawn == null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("ThingToSpawn is null for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        Instantiate (ThingToSpawn,Position,Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Instantiate something at one of positions randomly:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Vector3[] Positions;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject ThingToSpawn;
    void Start () 
    {
        if (ThingToSpawn == null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("ThingToSpawn is null for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        Instantiate (ThingToSpawn,Positions[Random.Range(0,3)],Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Choose three positions randomly and instantiate something at one them randomly. I'm not sure that having a public list of transform is a good solution, but Unity doesn't do well with constructors. (If you assing it only in inspector, make it private and use `[SerializeField]`)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Vector3> Positions;
    public List<Transform> Transforms=new List<Transform>();
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject ThingToSpawn;
    void Start () 
    {
        if (ThingToSpawn == null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("ThingToSpawn is null for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        if (Transforms == null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("Transforms variable is null for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        if (Transforms.Count == 0) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("No transforms provided for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        var positionsList =
            Enumerable.Range (0, 3)
                .Select (i => Transforms [Random.Range (0, Transforms.Count)].position)
                .ToList ();
        Positions = new ReadOnlyCollection<Vector3> (positionsList);

        Instantiate (ThingToSpawn,Positions[0],Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Choose three positions randomly. Instantiate something at one of them randomly. Check which is right, which is middle and which is left but do NOT care for overlaps.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<Transform> Transforms=new List<Transform>();
    public Vector3 LeftPosition{ get; private set;}
    public Vector3 MiddlePosition{ get; private set;}
    public Vector3 RightPosition{ get; private set;}
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject ThingToSpawn;
    void Start () 
    {
        if (ThingToSpawn == null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("ThingToSpawn is null for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        if (Transforms == null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("Transforms variable is null for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        if (Transforms.Count == 0) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("No transforms provided for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        var Positions = 
            Enumerable.Range (0, 3)
                .Select (i => Transforms [Random.Range(0,Transforms.Count)].position)
                .OrderBy (i => i.x)
                .ToList ();
        LeftPosition = Positions [0];
        MiddlePosition = Positions [1];
        RightPosition = Positions [2];
        Instantiate (ThingToSpawn,new[]{LeftPosition,MiddlePosition,RightPosition}[Random.Range(0,3)],Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Same as above, but care for overlaps. Split into two files

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<Transform> Transforms=new List<Transform>();
    public Vector3 LeftPosition{ get; private set;}
    public Vector3 MiddlePosition{ get; private set;}
    public Vector3 RightPosition{ get; private set;}
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject ThingToSpawn;
    void Start () 
    {
        if (ThingToSpawn == null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("ThingToSpawn is null for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        if (Transforms == null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("Transforms variable is null for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        if (Transforms.Count <= 3) 
        {
            Debug.LogError ("Less than 3 transforms provided for instance of Spawn.cs at "+transform.name);
            return;
        }
        var Positions = 
            Enumerable.Range (0, 3)
                .RandomShuffle()
                .Take(3)
                .Select (i => Transforms [i].position)
                .OrderBy (i => i.x)
                .ToList ();
        LeftPosition = Positions [0];
        MiddlePosition = Positions [1];
        RightPosition = Positions [2];
        Instantiate (ThingToSpawn,new[]{LeftPosition,MiddlePosition,RightPosition}[Random.Range(0,3)],Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

In `RNGUtils.cs`. Uses [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class RNGUtils
{
    static void SwapListElements<T>(IList<T> list, int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
    {
        T tmp = list[firstIndex];
        list[firstIndex]=list[secondIndex];
        list[secondIndex]=tmp;
    }
    public static IList<T> RandomShuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        List<T> res = enumerable.ToList ();
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; ++i) 
        {
            SwapListElements (res,i,Random.Range(i,res.Count));
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

As you can see, two last solutions above use syntax `new[]{a,b,c}[]`. [It is valid.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) The errors you mention are most likely compiler errors. They generally can be fixed one by one by googling their names and error codes.

In your code you assigned `int` to `Transform` and made some other errors which could be solved by looking at compiler errors. I suggest you to solve a few dozens of easiest tasks from sites like spoj/project euler, to not make basic mistakes. I use them every time I learn a new programming language

Hope this helps!